# How to dynamically pass user to Execute AS @username sql server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I need to run a stored proc with Execute AS @username(dynamic user) signature.

It works fine with hardcoded username however I want it to be dynamic and pass it depending on the environment it is running.

Example below, works fine however I want "OWNER" to be dynamic, parameterized etc like @username

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Demo2
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].table_2') AND type in (N'U'))
CREATE TABLE table_2 (id int, data nchar(10))
INSERT INTO table_2
```

Comment: You can't make an `WITH EXECUTE AS` dynamic. You *could* make an `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` or `EXECUTE AS USER` dynamic, with dynamic SQL, however, this feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Also, you state you want it to be parametrised "like `@username`", however, you have no parameter `@username` in your Stored Procedure?

Comment: Also, forgot to mention,  `EXECUTE AS LOGIN/USER` doesn't work the same way as `WITH EXECUTE AS` either. The `LOGIN`/`USER` would need permissions to impersonate the other `USER`/`LOGIN` to be able to make use of it. You really need to explain what your *real* goal is here. Why do you think you need a dynamic `WITH EXECUTE AS` clause? having something liek that feels more like a uge security risk, in my opinion.